# NoMethodError: Trying to call a model from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I do need some help with this error:
*NoMethodError in PostsController#checkin
undefined method `hasToday' for #*

**Controller:**

```
def checkin
    @date = DateTime.parse(params[:day])
    if (Post.hasToday(@date))
end
```

**Model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :created_on, lambda {|date| {:conditions => ['DATE(created_at) = ?', date.to_s(:db)]}}

  def hasToday(date)
    self.created_on(date).count > 0 ? true : false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

try this in your modal

```
    def self.hasToday(date)
         self.created_on(date).count > 0 ? true : false
    end
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I must prefix self.hasToday to make the method static.

Comment: FYI ruby method names traditionally use undercores, and are not camelcased. So to be more ruby-like it would be: self.has_today(date)